# call windows API function using a shellcode

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shellcode

**Goal**
I am trying a simple shellcode exercise - call "OutputDebugStringA" on a remote process using CreateRemoteThread that will activate a shellcode - this exercise is without dll injection!

**problem**
I dont know the address of "OutputDebugStringA" at the remote process, only at the local process.

**What I have been trying so far**

```
int main() {
char ShellCode[] = "\x48\x8d\x0c\x25\x10\x9c\x8c\x4c\xff\x14\x25\x00\x01\x8d\x4c";
/*
* Get process handle passing in the process ID.
*/
int32_t nProcID = 21440;
const HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, nProcID);
if (NULL == hProcess) {
    printf("Error: the specified process couldn't be found.\n");
}

const LPVOID arg = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(ShellCode), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
if (NULL == arg) {
    int32_t nLastErrorCode = GetLastError();
    printf("Error: the memory could not be allocated inside the chosen process. Error code - %d.\n", nLastErrorCode);
}

const int32_t nBytesWritten = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, arg, ShellCode, sizeof(ShellCode), NULL);
if (0 == nBytesWritten) {
    int32_t nLastErrorCode = GetLastError();
    printf("Error: there was no bytes written to the process's address space. Error code - %d.\n", nLastErrorCode);
}

const HANDLE hThreadID = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)arg , NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (NULL == hThreadID) {
    int32_t nLastErrorCode = GetLastError();
    printf("Error: the remote thread could not be created. Error code - %d.\n", nLastErrorCode);
}
else {
    printf("Success: the remote thread was successfully created.\n");
}

/*
* Close the handle to the process, because we've already injected the DLL.
*/
CloseHandle(hProcess);
getchar();

return 0;
```

}

**What I tried**
Dissemble OutputDebugStringA [picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adrBt.png)
then convert it to shellcode online and then call my code with the new shellcode. But the remote proccess is not familiar with these addresses.

Comment: That is not "shellcode" at all.  Simply create a DLL with the OutputDebugString() call, LoadLibrary() to inject it.

Comment: there are two exercises. The first one was to inject using a dll. In the second one you are supposed only to inject a shellcode by allocating memory at the remote process, write the shellcode and then call it using the CreatRemoteThread function

Comment: Enumerate the modules of the remote process. Find the module containing the function. Read that module's PE headers to work out where the entry point is.

Comment: You need the information about how OutputDebugString() was load in the remote process, then inject codes call to its true address.

Comment: No need to parse the PE headers. Figure out the offset of OutputDebugStringA relative to the module start address (HMODULE) in the current process, then apply the same offset in the target process.

Comment: @sev: Won't work, if you are running a 32-bit process and want to inject code into a 64-bit process.

Comment: Or vice versa. Right.

Comment: They are both 64 bit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the only thing you want to know is the address of `OutputDebugStringA`, (assuming that your shellcode does work), it is the same as the current process. So you can get it by doing `LPVOID function_addr = reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "OutputDebugStringA"));` Then you can use `function_addr` as you want.

Because `kernel32.dll` has the same base address in every process, the relative virtual address will be the same, and thus, the address will be the same.

Comment: Not correct in general. The base address of *kenel32.dll* is not the same in processes with different bitness. Since the question doesn't limit itself to processes of the same bitness, this proposed answer is only a partial solution.

Comment: In windows, the base address of ntdll.dll and kernel32.dll are always the same.

Comment: `0x00007FFFBC300000` and `0x748A0000` are undoubtedly not the same address. The former is the base address of kernel32.dll in a 64-bit process, the latter in a 32-bit process. On my system. Today.

Comment: You are correct. I was assuming the architectures would be the same.